# Using PHP Options in a Jquery Slider

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

So I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious on this. (I think it may have something to do with the incompatibility of the two languages, since as far as I'm aware PHP is interpreted on the server?)… I'm pretty new to PHP though.

I'm using the great Jquery Plugin ResponsiveSlides on the front page of my custom WordPress-based site. That works great, with this code:

```
$(".home-slides").responsiveSlides({
auto: true,
speed: 500,
pause: true,
timeout: 7000,
pager: true,
nav: true,
maxwidth: 1280,
namespace: "home-slides",
prevText: "",
nextText: "",
navContainer:".home-slides",
manualControls: "#home-tabs"
});
```

However, I want to be able to allow the client to have some control over the plugin, using custom fields on the home page in the wordpress backend. These custom fields can easily be called and correctly display in an alert:

```
var speed = <?php echo the_field( "speed" ); ?>;
var timeout = <?php echo the_field( "timeout" ); ?>;
```

However, if I try and insert them as variables or directly with the above PHP, I have no luck. The closest I've got is:

```
$(".home-slides").responsiveSlides({
auto: true,
speed: <?php echo the_field( "speed" ); ?>,
pause: true,
timeout: <?php echo the_field( "timeout" ); ?>,
pager: true,
nav: true,
maxwidth: 1280,
namespace: "home-slides",
prevText: "",
nextText: "",
navContainer:".home-slides",
manualControls: "#home-tabs"
});
```

Which displays correctly in the live page source (i.e. `timeout: 7000` etc), but breaks the slider. Is there anyway to make this work? Am I missing something?

Thank you all!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Tom Kriek's suggestion, I can echo the script correctly. This produces the correct script in the live page source, but the slider still doesn't work. However, if I copy that same script from the page source to the actual file and test this, it works perfectly. It appears for some reason the browser is ignoring the script when PHP echoed.

Comment: if it works when hardcoded but not when generated dynamically there must be a problem with the output, right click in browser and view page source, and post here the rendered output

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to echo the whole script tag as well.

Comment: There's always a better solution to set dynamically javascript variables rather than hardcoding php variables. Consider outputing the php variables in a JSON object, then use that object for getting the information. That way your javascript file will be left intact.

Comment: Could be the user can define these properties in a backpanel and generates the scripts like that. I agree it's not a clean way of doing it but it's what the OP wants.

Comment: @Jacob, is this a javascript file? if yes, you can't simply put PHP in it, unless if its a dynamically generated JS (using .php). What is the source of this file?

Comment: Using the PHP, the page source for the actual page would show the correct code (i.e. what I put in the first code box). Which is what puzzled me, because the code *IS* there, but for some reason it's being ignored.

And yes - it's a PHP file, and correct I'm justing using a pretty straightforward plugin to generate the fields in the backend for the client to fill in.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".home-slides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: true,
    speed: '. the_field("speed") .',
    pause: true,
    timeout: '. the_field("timeout") .',
    pager: true,
    nav: true,
    maxwidth: 1280,
    namespace: "home-slides",
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    navContainer:".home-slides",
    manualControls: "#home-tabs"
});
</script>';
```

Comment: Tried this with two variables declared before the script tag and succesfully interpolates it. I think the <?php tag inside the script tag was messing it up.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, it feels like the right direction… I've just tried echoing the script, but according to the page's source (live), it appears to be printing the numbers from the PHP fields as text directly above the script and then producing the script with blanks where the PHP fields should be inserting their values...

Comment: Do you have a live version or demo version of the site or post a screenshot of the result in your answer.

Comment: Could also be another jquery script running on top of this one constantly replacing the contents with a set of default values. Have you tried checked all the .js files running on your Wordpress installation and see what they do? Have you tried resizing the window see if the slider changes along with it. Might very well be a script that changes the content based on the dimensions of the window the website is in.

Comment: Okay, so messing around a bit, echoing each part of the script in a separate `<?php echo ?>` produces the correct code in the live page source. But that script appears not to have any affect on the page, and doesn't create the slider. However, (weirdly), I can copy and paste that very same script from the live page source into the actual file, save, re-upload, and that makes the slider work perfectly.

So it would seem that there is some problem in the browser reading the script that is created through PHP??

Comment: Do you not have a demo website or test location for me to inspect?

Comment: I am "obliged" not to permit "unauthorised third parties" access to the demo before the client has agreed to go live (I know...). Wondering if anyone might be able to think of a reason that the browser would ignore a script? I'm pretty sure it's not at JS file interfering.

Comment: Have you checked the console on your browser to see if it's not the script firing an error?

Comment: `the_field` already does an `echo`, it has to be `get_the_field`

Answer (score 1):

To incorporate jQuery plugins into WordPress it's a matter of enqueuing the scripts in the correct order (with [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)) and to pass our custom meta data to the JavaScript file (with [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)).

A simple example, note that JS files are inside the plugin sub-folder `/my-plugin/js/`. The `MAIN-PLUGIN-FILE.js` corresponds to the jQuery plugin files (slider, player, gallery), add more `wp_register_script` as needed. And the `CUSTOM-CONFIG.js` file contains the plugin's initialization.

**`plugin.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Simple jQuery plugin enqueue
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25531753/1287812
 * Author: brasofilo 
*/

class SO_25527828
{
    private $plugin_url;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
    }

    public function enqueue()
    {
        # Enqueue only on specific places
        # http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
        if( !is_home() && !is_front_page() )
            return;

        # Can be anything from unheap.com
        wp_register_script(
            'main_plugin',
            $this->plugin_url . 'js/MAIN-PLUGIN-FILE.js'
        );

        # You'll have to play with dependencies, on_footer and do separately wp_enqueue_script's
        # to achieve the exact HTML that the jQ plugin requires 
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'config_plugin', 
            $this->plugin_url . 'js/CUSTOM-CONFIG.js', 
            array( 'jquery', 'main_plugin' ), // dependencies
            false, // version
            true // on footer
        );

        # Pass PHP values to JS
        wp_localize_script( 
            'config_plugin', 
            'my_cfg', 
            array(
                'url'    => $this->plugin_url, // To load stuff from the plugin's dir
                'option' => get_option( 'my_option' ), // Your custom config values, simple value or full object
            )
        );
    }
}
new SO_25527828();
```

**`CUSTOM-CONFIG.js`**, the `my_cfg` var is printed on header and contains the values that we localized

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{   
    console.dir(my_cfg);
});
```

Comment: This isn't a WordPress plugin, it's really just quite a lightweight piece of Jquery - http://responsiveslides.com. Does this still need to be enqueued?

Comment: It's best practice enqueue JS files. And creating a plugin  incorporates it as an individual package, maybe just adding some output on a template `<?php function_from_plugin(); ?>`. But if it is fully integrated into the theme then just change the function `plugin_url()` for `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615).